# What is this climbing plant with three-lobed leaves and furled petals?

Tags: identification, vines

The flower bloomed. Here it is. This is morning glory right?[image]

[image]

The flower has not bloomed yet. This is the leaf:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing Ipomea, probably I. indica, by the look of the furled flower, and the leaves do appear to have three lobes, at least, I think the one I can partially see does. As to which particular variety, need to see the flower open.

If this plant isn't a climber/trailer/twiner, then this answer is wrong.

UPDATE: You've confirmed its a climber, it is one of the Ipomeas, commonly known as Morning Glory - there are many varieties with variously coloured flowers.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to know the name. I m a,big fan of flower plants:-) I ll post the photo after the flower blooms :-)

Comment: Okay - in future, remember that for ID purposes, the foliage and growth habit of a plant is as important as any flower produced

Comment: Yep, Ipomea (morning glory) as I said.... pretty colour